# Why is float.min different between C++ and C#?

Tags: c#, c++

In C# I have (saw with Visual Studio watch tool) :

```
float.MinValue = -3.40282347E+38
```

And in C++ :

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::min() = 1.17549435e-038
```

Why are the values not the same? And how can I get `-3.40282347E+38` (C# value) in C++ ?

Comment: Did you read their documentation? Did you come across `std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()`?

Comment: I believe you're comparing the minimum value to the minimum finite value (that is the smallest positive value that can be represented)

Comment: Because one is the largest negative value and the other is the smallest positive value. They're both "minimal" but in different senses.

Comment: You are comparing a negative value with a positive number.  The c++ number is the accuracy of the value (LSB) which c# is giving the largest negative value.

Comment: The first is `-(1-2^-24)×2^128` (max finite negative float value) and the second is `2^-126` (min normalized positive float value).

Comment: You are looking for float.Epsilon.  Still not the same due to the difference between normalized and denormal values.  One of the things they could not agree on when they created the IEEE-754 standard.  The MSDN article for Single.Epsilon points this out, noting that ARM cores are different.  ARM does not support denormal values, Intel cores do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for [`numeric_limits::lowest`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest). As stated there:

> Returns the lowest finite value representable by the numeric type T,
>   that is, a finite value x such that there is no other finite value y
>   where y < x. This is different from `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` for
>   floating-point types.

Comment: To be completely fair he might have been looking for `float.Epsilon` instead :D

Comment: Well, he asked how he can get -3.40282347E+38 in C++, not for the epsilon value.

Comment: Yes, lowest is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The two values you're showing are two different things. The first one, -3.40282347E+38, is a **large negative** value; it's the smallest value that can be represented as a float. The second one, 1.17549435e-038, is a **tiny non-negative** value; it's the smallest number greater than 0 that can be represented.